# Visual studio installer - sign files inside MSI

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, signing

I have to sign both of projects output and msi installers.
I can use singtool for setup.exe and setup.msi.

But what should I do for sign installed project outputs: (e.g. C:\program files\my app\run.exe)

I read in other thread there is a way for signing files in \bin or \obj directory but it doesn't work. I use VS 2010 pro - C# project.

Answer (score 1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/e9dce89d-78ed-463b-bcb2-8f7a57e2a20e

second post

Sign it in post build events in project properties.